# Tomcat classloader violates delegating policy

Tags: java, tomcat, classloader

- Question1:
  As we know, when a classloader is about to load a class, it delegates the request to its parent classloader. However in Tomcat, it doesn’t: you could load your class to overwrite the same name class which is put in common lib directory. This means Tomcat `WebappClassloader` doesn’t follow delegating policy. Is it violation of convention?
- Question2:
  I wrote a class and put it in common lib directory, obviously the class is shared among web apps. For instance, every web app can read/write the static field of the class. Further, classes in JDK are loaded by Bootstrap classloader, then their static fields are shared by any web apps, is it dangerous?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This behavior is intentional and it allows you to override libraries provided in the Tomcat itself independently in every WAR. For instance you can override Log4J with different version per each application deployed to the container without introducing any issues or breaking other applications. From Tomcat [documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html):

> Like many server applications, Tomcat installs a variety of class loaders [...] to **allow different portions of the container, and the web applications running on the container**, to **have access to different repositories of available classes and resources**. This mechanism is used to provide the functionality defined in the Servlet Specification, version 2.4 — in particular, Sections 9.4 and 9.6.

It does violate the normal delegation algorithm, but this is how other application server work as well (JBoss for instance).

**Ad. question 2**: Yes, it is dangerous, you have to remember about synchronization and have no control over who modifies this variable. I would avoid `static` fields altogether.

For instance [EhCache](http://www.ehcache.org/) allows you to share [`CacheManager`](http://ehcache.org/apidocs/net/sf/ehcache/CacheManager.html). This is implemented via `net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager#singleton` `static volatile` field. Now you get all sort of problems: if you put `ehcache.jar` in Tomcat's `/lib`, it will work as expected. However if each web application has its own copy of the JAR file, sharing will not work because each web app has its own copy of `CacheManager` class. It gets even worse when only one application has its own `ehcache.jar` - all applications will share the same instance of `CachedManager` except the one having `ehcache.jar` packaged together. Such error are very hard to track down...

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yes, every app server should "violate" the delegation algorithm.