# Is it safe to share a single Classloader for common libraries across multiple <Host> elements?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, log4j, c3p0

Here is a snippet from my server.xml file in Tomcat:

```
<Host name="client9001.example.com" appBase="/web/my-product-code" autoDeploy="true"></Host>
<Host name="client9002.example.com" appBase="/web/my-product-code" autoDeploy="true"></Host>
<Host name="client9003.example.com" appBase="/web/my-product-code" autoDeploy="true"></Host>
...
<Host name="client9254.example.com" appBase="/web/my-product-code" autoDeploy="true"></Host>
```

It is well-known that every `Host` element creates its own `WebappClassloader` instance, which makes every host be totally isolated and safe. With this setup I can safely use one Tomcat instance to serve X customers, each one being served under a different subdomain. This setup prevents customer A's objects to be manipulated by customer B's actions.

However, this creates a non-scalable need for non-heap space (since every class is loaded X times) and I was wondering if I could create a shared class loader for all the hosts. I know that Tomcat supports that kind of thing (using the "Common" class loader in https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html#Class_Loader_Definitions) but my question is whether it is safe to do so. I mean, I can make my own classes safe by eliminating all static fields but is this enough? I'm worried about the 3rd party libraries, like the Spring Framework, Log4J, Joda-time and several others that come with my product code.

I have already used reflection to identify all the static variables in those classes and I have discovered literally 252 static-and-non-final fields and 5772 static-and-final fields, and that's all in 3rd party code (my own code has only 3 fields that I will eliminate).

Should I go down this road and review all those 6027 fields? I mean, is this whole idea a bad idea? If so, then what kind of code could ever be shared in the "Common" class loader?

Is there any strong evidence that all these famous frameworks are safe to be shared like this or should I treat everything as unsafe-until-proven-otherwise?

Comment: If lots of applications share c3p0 in one `ClassLoader`, you may need to be careful that you each one gets their own (named) configuration rather than relying on the (unnamed) per-`ClassLoader` default. See https://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#named_configurations

Comment: Thank you, @SteveWaldman, that's great to know. It will be useful when I go down this road.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would be really cautious ... and decide if performance is worth the risk

I was thinking of hypothetical situation where you could have some unintended consequences of using shared ClassLoader...

I took a look at `Log4J` which creates loggers through `LogManager` which extends `java.util.logging.LogManager` which is used to maintain a set of shared state about Loggers and log services.

Imagine the case where these clients do  `private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger();` to create loggers for each host

```
 <Host name="client9001.example.com">  
 <Host name="client9002.example.com">
 <Host name="client9003.example.com"> 

 <Host name="BADclient.example.com">
```

Because the LogManager is statically shared between all hosts, the bad client can call `LogManagers.getLoggerNames();` which would return a list of all registered loggers to that static LogManager instance and would  leak information about other clients running on the same tomcat instance / be able to remove the eventlisteners for the other hosts using that same class ( **I haven't tried this **)

Basically you want to put code that would be 100% shared between all hosts (and all future hosts) running on the the JVM. The common example would be initializing JDBC connection.

Also in terms of code maintenance, if you were going to go down the rabbit hole, and try to review all static methods/fields .. with every update of the 3rd party imports you would have to review them again an make sure nothing was introduced ... and maybe even review the imports of the 3rd party imports

Might find this question intresting [Tomcat classloader violates delegating policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7358681/tomcat-classloader-violates-delegating-policy) as he asks about the danger of using common class loaders in Tomcat

Comment: Yeah, I think you are right. It opens up a ton of issues. I think it would be wiser to make the app be a multi-tenant app instead. What do you think?

Comment: So I think again its going to depend on what the end goal is for the application (security vs. resource usage/efficiency)... With every host having there isolated classes, there is a significantly smaller chance of different clients affecting the data/session of other clients, but like you said this will duplicate class loading among other things, if you create a multi-tenant application you will still have all the pitfalls that shared class loader for common classes are ( minus maybe some of the implementation complexity) ...however  if one client makes the app go down they all go down.